# Showing that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} = 2 \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1 + x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I was reading an article in which it was stated that, with a change of variable, one could show that:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} = 2 \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1 + x^2}$$

I tried with $t = 1 + \frac{1}{x}$ but that doesn't work out, especially because the lower bound doesn't become $0$.

Comment: Use $u=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: @YourAdHere: Then how do I change the bounds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the substitution $u=\frac{1}{x}$ we get

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_0^1 \frac{u^{-2}}{1+u^{-2}}du=\int_0^1 \frac{du}{1+u^2}$$

which implies

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} + \int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = 2\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Nice, I got it. In the first passage of the first line you missed some steps; it took me a good 6 minutes to work it out!

Comment: @rubik: We don't want to spoil all the practice :).

Comment: @downvoter: What is your objection?

Comment: Just wondering, how do you see downvotes? Clicking on the vote like on StackOverflow does not work.

Comment: @rubik: (1) It does work, but you need a certain amount of reputation. (2) You get -2 reputation for a downvote, that shows up on your summary.

Comment: Oh thanks, I was suspecting something like that!

Answer (score 6):

You just need to show that $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$; this follows by the substitution $u=1/x$.

Answer (score 5):

Or just by calculation:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}= [\arctan(x)]_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{2}\pi$$ and

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}= [\arctan(x)]_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{4}\pi$$